# Gnuplottex and Texshop -- Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input!

Tags: packages, texshop, gnuplot, paths, ghostscript

I'm trying to compile the following file using latex and the gnuplottex package. For some reason I'm getting this error, even though I have already enabled shell escape and `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot` is on my `$PATH`...
Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] %graph
\centering

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color]
plot x
\end{gnuplot}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
Opening gnuplot stream relatorio-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot
(./relatorio-gnuplottex-fig1.texepstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 36129 2015-01-24 00:30:11Z karl $) 2.23
!!! Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input: gs -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=relatorio-gnuplottex-fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages#/None - -c quit
```

Comment: Welcome! Does it work on the command line? (That is, is this an editor problem or not?)

Comment: do you have `gs` (ghostscript) installed in your path? it is that command rather than gnuplot, that isn't found, or isn't running

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do have gs in my path. 
$PATH:usr/local/bin/gs

Comment: @cfr Hi! You were right! It is an editor problem. I searched how to compile latex files using the terminal and, after enabling shell-escape, it worked. 
It's nice that I can manually compile the file, but it would be even nicer if I could use Texshop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of OS X do you have, which version of MacTeX, is TeX Live up-to-date and is TeXShop the latest available?

Comment: I have changed to El Captain. And reinstalled pretty much everything, so all MacTeX  and TeXShop are up to date. (MacTex 2015)